# Make Google Maps Markers draggable within region/area?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

I am creating markers based on my location and I would like to make the markers draggable within 1km of that location.

So, basically I want to know how to make a marker draggable within a certain area/region only and not the entire map.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You have to define *bounds* and check if the new position is outside the bounds in the `onDragListener` of the marker: if the new position is outside the bounds you can reset the marker to the last valid position or do whatever you want.

To match if the marker is-or-not inside the bounds you must use the method `contains` of the [LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLngBounds#contains%28com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng%29) object.

Something like this:

```
LatLngBounds bounds;
LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

// You construct your bounds in a way like this
builder.include(new LatLng(latitude1, longitude1));
builder.include(new LatLng(latitude2, longitude2));
builder.include(new LatLng(latitude3, longitude3));
// etc

bounds = builder.build();

googleMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {

        if (bounds.contains(marker.getPosition())) {
            // cast your spell
        } else {
            // you can't drag here
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: If the solution is correct please set it as accepted.